# Anypoint Studio - Debugger is not launching

Tags: mule, esb, mule-studio, anypoint-studio

I could not launch "Anypoint Studio Version: 5.3.0" debugger for ESB Mule project.

When I clicked debug option from drop down menu for corresponding project, the console tab is running with INFO message. But in "Mule Debugger" tab shows that "Mule Debugger is not running. Launch your mule application in debug". I tried restarting anypoint studio and setting different ports to the debugger. But still same issue.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Issue got resolved !
I have changed port to 9999 from 6666.

Earlier i have tried changing port from 6666 to 6667/6668/6669..  These ports are not working for me. So i have tried with 9999. It resolved the issue.

Comment: great you've posted the answer. 99% of the cases this is the issue. That 666* range is blocked by virusscanners/firewalls often.