# Mule Eclipse Debug Remote Mule Application Not breaking at breakpoints

Tags: eclipse, debugging, mule, mule-studio, mule-component

I am using mule version 3.4.2. I am using eclipse IDE(Version: Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2)). I installed Anypoint studio plugin and am able to see all the pictorial view of flows.
When I am trying to Debug through the flows using Remote mule Debug, the debugger is not stopping at specified breakpoint. 
Whenever there is an exception though it breaks at some random point.

I am using the default mule launcher configuration
-M-Dmule.debug.enable=true -M-Dmule.debug.suspend=false -M-Dmule.debug.port=6666

when i start mule remotely I do,
$MULE_HOME/mule -M-Dmule.debug.enable=true -M-Dmule.debug.suspend=false -M-Dmule.debug.port=6666

Should i do anything different to be able to break at specified break points?

FYI, I am able to use use Remote Java Application and have no issues in breaking through the java code break points.

Answer (score 1):

Please Refer the below links, seems to have a similar one:
[Anypoint Studio - Debugger is not launching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34281992/anypoint-studio-debuger-is-not-launching)
and 
https://forums.mulesoft.com/questions/1160/cant-debug-in-anypoint-studio.html