# MuleSoft Debugger not working

Tags: debugging, mule, mule-studio, anypoint-studio

I am trying to debug in my anypoint studio and debugger does not seems to be working.
I performed following steps PROJECT_NAME --> Right Click --> Debug As --> Mule Application.

Application has successfully deployed however debugging is not working. I see a message as "Mule Debugger is not working. Launch your Mule application in debug."

Also confirmed my application has successfully deployed, once deployed I sent a request and I dont see anything in Mule Debugger.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

I even gave a try by changing port numbers also by killing everything that might be running in port 6666.

Comment: Oh forgot to mention I have toggled breakpoint as well.

Comment: did you manage to solve the issue? could you share what approach worked?

Comment: Havnt solved it @Alberici. Several people gave several options for some reason none worked out for me.

Comment: sorry @DJD, did you try using a new workspace? I know is not a clean solution, but it can help diagnosing this issue

Comment: Been there done that! Still no luck my friend.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your Debugger Port. By default it should be 6666. I've changed mine to 1024 and it worked:

[image]

Comment: Please use hyperlink appropriately. Right now, it is not obvious which part of the answer is exactly connected to the link.

Comment: Apologies, I got a prompt from Stack Overflow that says I'm not allowed to post images until I have gotten 10 points.

Answer (score 0):

Try closing Anypoint Studio and clean all metadata. Start debugging the flow again.

Comment: Been there done that, still same and hence I have to post this here.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the link for same issue here- https://forums.mulesoft.com/questions/1678/mule_debugger_not_working.html

Comment: I looked at this before and all it says is to change port numbers from 6666 to 8888 and none of those solutions have worked for me hence I have created this new question and I have also mentioned that I tried changing my port numbers in my question description and still seeking help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you had a break point in any  component of the flow and try again.
2. Having a break point looks like the image below

[image]

Comment: Santosh thanks for your answer, fortunately I am not a newbie for programming nor for mulesoft. Just this case seems to be so weird and does not work even though I had a enabled breakpoint.

Answer (score 0):

You may have a 'zombie' Mule process running in the background occupying the debugger port. Try running the following command to list the processes on that port:

```
lsof -i:6666
```

Answer (score 0):

try to change the ports as it might be already used,If that also is not working then Re Install of Anypoint Studio  which would solve this problem.

Could you try giving higher port number like 9999 or more if you are running on Windows OS.

Comment: @DJD Could you try giving higher port number like 9999 if you are running on Windows OS.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34281992/anypoint-studio-debuger-is-not-launching

Answer (score 0):

Create a new workspace and try again.

To know if the issue is always happening or if it is something in particular in your ws

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but slightly different. My Mule app was not deploying in Debug mode, it was taking forever.

I tried changing the port number, and it didn't work.

I eventually solved the issue by reinstalling Anypoint and configuring it again.

Answer (score 0):

You can try couple of things like changing port from 9999 to 6666 and vice versa. If it still doesn't work restart Anypoint Studio.